# ¿Cómo puedo renombrar una etiqueta en Git?

Tags: git, git-tag

Resulta que estoy haciendo una aplicación y me puse a versionar con `0.1`, `0.2`, etc. Ahora me doy cuenta de que estas versiones realmente eran `2.1`, `2.2`, etc. y querría cambiar el nombre de esas etiquetas (*tags*).

Sé que podría ir a cada tag, buscar el commit, crear un tag, etc. pues un tag no puede editarse. Sin embargo, ¿hay alguna forma más rápida?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/1983854

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Si quieres renombrar la etiqueta `vieja` por `nueva`, debes seguir estos pasos:

```
git tag nueva vieja
git tag -d vieja
git push origin :refs/tags/vieja
git push --tags
```

Es decir:

1. Crea una etiqueta 'nueva' a partir de 'vieja'
2. Elimina la etiqueta vieja localmente
3. Elimina la etiqueta vieja del repositorio
4. Sube los cambios realizados en las etiquetas

Información extraída de [How do you rename a Git tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719854/1983854) y completada posteriormente.